# Two macros that "complete" eachother

Tags: macros, system-verilog

EDIT: seems to be working now

I'm trying to write two macros that will be used to wrap any code. For example:

```
`define start_of_macro()begin\
fork\
  begin\
    #20us;\
  end\
  begin\
end
```

and the second part:

```
`define end_of_macro()begin\
  end\
join_any disable_fork;\
end
```

And use it something like this:

```
`start_of_macro
  while(1)begin #20ns; end
`end_of_macro
```

I keep on getting errors due to the fact that each macro isn't legal on it's own. Any way to overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't show nearly enough code to help. Remember that text macros don't know anything about SystemVerilog syntax, so it should be ok each macro is not legal SystemVerilog syntax on its own. But you need to show us what you want the result to look like.

Comment: make sure that there is a space between `) begin` and there should be no spaces afteer `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to fork something in parallel to the 20 microsecond wait. You have an extra `end` in the opening macro. It should be:

```
`define start_of_macro()\
  begin\
    fork\
      begin\
        #20us;\
      end\
      begin
```

You also have an extra `begin` in the closing macro. It should be:

```
`define end_of_macro()\
      end\
    join_any\
    disable_fork;\
  end
```

After macro expansion, the code that goes between the opening and the closing macros will be reside between a `begin` (from `start_of_macro`) and an `end` (from `end_of_macro`).

Comment: It's the end of the macro

Comment: Macros don't need `begin`/`end` statement's.